# Is there a maximum length for a protocol name?

Tags: uri, protocols, string-length, maxlength

In a URI, we have several parts. The first part is the protocol, such as `http`, `ftp`, `smtp`, etc. Is there an RFC or similar document that limits the length of the protocol?

From what I can see in my `/etc/services` file, the length remains very short, but I would imagine it could be much longer than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no formal restriction on length or "scheme" portion of the Uri (which you call "protocol") - [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1)

> scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )

You may also refer to web protocols - relationship between Uri schema (like http or ftp) and web protol (like HTTP or FTP) covered in [URI Schemes and Web Protocols](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/SchemeProtocols.html).

Comment: I was definitely referring to schemes.